# How do I add one blank page after both these pages?

Tags: clearpage, vspace, shipout

I have two inetial pages in my document. I need to leave blank pages after both pages explicitely. \shipout\null is not working properly. How should I add that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,times,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}\sloppy
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\LARGE \textbf{Main Heading in the page}
\end{center}
\vfill \thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you use explicit markup to set a heading? Should this be something like a title page? If so you should use the `titlepage` environment for it. If it should be the start of a part of your document, the `\part` macro would be the correct choice.

Comment: @Skillmon I prepared title page separately and included it using \input{}

Comment: So what is the reasoning for this "Main Heading in the page" thingy? Which purpose should it solve? It looks incorrect to do it the way you did, imho.

Comment: @Skillmon The main concern is to have two blank pages one after the other

Comment: I don't mean the blank pages, I got that and you got an answer for it (just putting anything invisible on the page and then a `\clearpage` or `\pagebreak` or what ever does add a blank page, maybe you'd want to also include a `\thispagestyle{empty}`: `\clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage` would shipout the current page and add another completely blank one after it). My point is that the code your showing us does something in a maybe improper way. I don't write this to annoy you or something, just want to give advice on how some things are to be done.

Comment: So: What is the purpose of the page containing only "Main Heading in the page"?

Comment: @Skillmon it means horizontal plus vertical centered heading only. I somehow did using vfill and vspaces

Comment: Do you use more than one of those "horizontal plus vertical centered heading"s? Should this heading end up in the Table of Contents?

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,times,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\begin{document}
\sloppy 
\vspace*{\fill} 
\begin{center} 
\LARGE \textbf{Main Heading in the page} 
\end{center} \vfill{}
\pagebreak

\ \thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak


\lipsum[1-2] 
\pagebreak
\ \thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to add `\thispagestyle{empty}` to suppress the output of page numbers (and additional content of the page header and footer).

Comment: @Skillmon It helped.